# I want to link a library in react native version 0.70.1 but I got a error error: unknown command 'link'

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

I want to link a library in react native version 0.70.1 but I got a error error: unknown command 'link' after trying this command react-native link react-native-notification-sounds[image]

Answer (score 1):

Linking is [automatic](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) since React Native 0.60. So no need to run `react-native link`.

After installing the library -

1. on android, just rebuild the app

```
npm run android
```

2. on ios, install the pod before rebuilding the app

```
npx pod-install ios
npm run ios
```

Answer (score 0):

"link" command in React native has been deprecated in version 69, instead you can go for :

```
npm i react-native-asset or yarn add react-native-asset
```